# Order By using case with conditional results and partition row_number()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL that I've not been able to return the order correctly.  Below is example of the rows and the order I want them to appear in.  I tried ORDER BY WITH CONDITIONAL CASE AND ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTION without success.  I want ColA to be the primary sort and ColB secondary only when ColC has a length < 3 otherwise ColB is primary and ColA is secondary

```
ColA      ColB      ColC            
5   750 15  
5   750 15  
3   984 13  
3   984 13  
5   1021    15  
5   1021    15  
4   1602    14  
4   1602    14  
4   1823    14  
4   1823    14  
6   4099    16  
6   4099    16  
11  4099    240990  
0   10880   10  
0   10880   10  
3   10881   13  
3   10881   13  
2   11053   12  
8   11053   211053  
6   10891   16  
6   10891   16  
2   11034   12  
10  11034   211034  

ColA      ColB      ColC            
0   10880   10  
0   10880   10  
2   11034   12  
10  11034   211034  
2   11053   12  
8   11053   211053  
3   984 13  
3   984 13  
3   10881   13  
3   10881   13  
4   1602    14  
4   1602    14  
4   1823    14  
4   1823    14  
5   750 15  
5   750 15  
5   1021    15  
5   1021    15  
6   4099    16  
6   4099    16  
11  4099    240990  
6   10891   16  
6   10891   16
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

```
order by case when len(ColC) < 3 then ColA else ColB end, 
    case when len(ColC) < 3 then ColB else ColA end
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1567/1)

Comment: this is what I tried initially and it does not work. It list all ColA with len < 3 then list all ColC  > 3 in ColB, ColA order

Comment: I added a SQL Fiddle example, above. Please tell me which rows are wrong, and what rule they are breaking.

Comment: This first rule broke was 10  11034   211034 was next to last line.  It did not keep  ColB all together

Comment: {11 4099 240990}   
{10 11034 211034 }  
{8 11053 211053  }